# Как мне изменить имена папок в гит? (с больших букв на маленькие)

Tags: git, github, репозиторий

Недавно начал осваивать гит. Когда я делал первый пуш в репозиторий на гитхабе, случайно назвал директории с большой буквы. Хотел поменять регистр первых букв в папках, но команда git add * почему-то отказывается распознавать регистр и пушит всё как и раньше с большой буквы, либо же вообще говорит что изменений никаких не было. Как это исправить? Можно ли напрямую как-нибудь переименовать папки в репозитории? Регистр здесь важен т.к. все эти директории являются пакетами и при импорте интерпретатор может просто напросто их не увидеть.

Comment: Чтобы переименовать папку используйте `git mv Папка папка`

Comment: @Denis640Kb Rename from 'Папка' to 'папка/Папка' failed. Should I try again? Вот что выдаёт. Не знаете почему может выводиться такое сообщение? Все процессы работающие с папкой вроде закрыты. Кстати просто mv без git впереди работает нормально.

Comment: Может какой-то файл блокировать выполнения действий. Попробуйте запустить под админом.

Comment: гит не отслеживает папки. Создайте папки с новыми именами, а затем с помощью `git mv Папка/файл.расш папка/файл.расш` перенесите туда все нужные файлы, затем сделайте добавление в индекс и коммит. А потом можно будет удалить старые пустые папки.

Comment: @Bulson Мда, ну и заморочек с этим. Так я ещё,мало того, на винде работаю, где регистр не учитывается, короче 40 минут потратил чтоб разобраться. Обычная вроде же операция :D Спасибо вам кстати огромное за помощь, ваш способ сработал!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая особенность есть не только в git, но и во многих сторонних файловых менеджерах под windows.

В таких случаях переименование нужно делать в два этапа, с промежуточным именем:

```
git mv Папка папка1
git mv папка1 папка
```